# Do book permutations improve book ciphers?

Tags: encryption

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1MfK8-Fv5Y7rcRz1Cp_swsZhJcgcILmyd?usp=sharing
*
Someone out there has built a book cipher using permutations of the book.  The basic premise seems to be that a book which is half a million words long can be rearranged in 10**2000000 ways (the factorial of half a million).  A text message is enciphered using one of the permutations of the book. Even if an attacker has a copy of the book, and has the software presented in the link, they simply cannot test a cipher message against all the permutations of the book.

The example persuades me...does it persuade anyone else?

Comment: Persuade anyone of what? That it's a valid cipher? That it should be used to encrypt sensitive data? Or that it's a neat permutation for hobby problems?

Comment: Note that books tend to repeat words, so n factorial is not the correct number of possible permutations

Comment: What about known plaintext? Chosen plaintext? Chosen ciphertext? Side channels? The number of possible mappings may be huge but that doesn't mean it's a secure algorithm.